# Select with lookbehind/lookahead regex

Tags: regex, regex-group

Been trying to figure this out and looking around. Maybe there is a way without lookbeahind or lookahead much easier, let me know.

Basically I have lots of rows with the following structure:

```
Item Received during transaction ZZZZZZ; Time spent: XXms ; Time expected: 
YYms; Date dd-mm-YYYY
```

Ideally I would only to be left with  the values XX;YY that make reference to the ms but haven't managed to find the correxct expression. The lenght of the lines is variable so I can't use fix values, any ideas?

Comment: You could capture anything between a whitespace and ms in an ungreedy way?

Comment: Right, will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will found a whitespace, then collect at least one non-whitespace character into the first group until it finds an "ms"

`\s(\S+)ms`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hima7k/1)